# C# - Load event not firing on second form

Tags: c#, .net

I want a basic checkbox to be checked upon load on the form, this Works in my main form just perfectly. But when i try to do the same on my second form (Gets called from a button) nothing happens. No syntax errors either.

Here is the code that starts the second form from a button (Keep in mind load events handles perfectly in this form)

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Analyser f2 = new Analyser();
    f2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    f2.ShowDialog(); // Shows Form2
}
```

And the Complete second form:

```
// Include libraries
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// Define and start the form
namespace Vis_Maskininformasjon
{
    public partial class Analyser : Form
    {
        public Analyser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // On Form Load
        public void Analyser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkBox3.Checked = true;
        }

        // Checkboxes            
        private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `Load` event hooked up in the designer for the second form?

Comment: That solved it! It was missing :) Thanks for fast answer

Answer (score 0):

the load event should fire and if not there is something wrong. Can you try to set a breakpoint to the line where the Load event is set in the InitializeComponent Method and when you reach this breakpoint add this Properties to the watch:

this.IsHandleCreated

this.Visible

both should be false at this point. If one of them is true you have perhaps some code (or a event) in your initialization that shows the form bevore the load event is set.

Seems like some one was able to resolve such a behavior here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/53cf3329-d603-44c8-a5de-ac28b4d89111/form-load-event-not-firing?forum=csharpgeneral